# How do i make Selenium pull out the sidebar menu tree

Tags: selenium

I have a iframe-sidebar which appears as soon as a widget is hovered over , since it uses the onchange javascript event,  and hides back when the sidebar is clicked again. There is a listbox in this sidebar which needs to be clicked for my chain to continue. How do i program Selenium webdriver in Python to pull out this sidebar ?

Thanks

On reading answers to question, I added this :-

```
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="leftSiderBarForm:moduleMenu"]')
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("leftSiderBarForm:moduleMenu")
    hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
    hover.perform()
```

but get error :-

```
MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: u'Offset within element cannot be scrolled into view: (72.5, 8.5): [object XrayWrapper [object HTMLSelectElement]]' ;
```

This is the HTML of that element that i copied from Chrome. I changed actual values to ABC and so on.

```
<select id="leftSiderBarForm:moduleMenu" name="leftSiderBarForm:moduleMenu" class="comboboxnowidth leftSideMenuSelect " size="1" onchange="jQuery('.submitMenuSelection').click()" style="z-index: 0;"> <option value="">-- Select --</option>
<option value="ABC">abc</option>
<option value="DEF">def</option>
```

Could i use Javascript to trigger that Jquery ?

Comment: I think you can use Actions class to hover over the widget and then perform click operation on the side bar as the element will be visible.

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

def hover_over_item(self):
    driver = webdriver_connection.connection
    element = driver.find_element_by_id(locator)
    hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
    hover.perform()
```

[Reference](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains)

Comment: Could you please read the edited question after your answer and see if you can find any fault with what i did.